# After upgrading php version from 7.3 to 8.1 LaravelGettext not working

Tags: php, laravel-8

Hi after upgrading PHP version 7.3 to 8.1 zerospam/laravel-gettext is not working below is the error:

[Wed Oct  5 10:07:23 2022] PHP Fatal error:  Declaration of Xinax\LaravelGettext\FileLoader\Cache\ApcuFileCacheLoader::loadResource($resource) must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Translation\Loader\FileLoader::loadResource(string $resource): array in C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\FileLoader\Cache\ApcuFileCacheLoader.php on line 40
[Wed Oct  5 10:07:23 2022] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class "Xinax\LaravelGettext\FileLoader\Cache\ApcuFileCacheLoader" not found in C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony.php:114
Stack trace:
#0 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony.php(63): Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony->createTranslator()
#1 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony.php(77): Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony->getTranslator()
#2 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony.php(35): Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony->setLocale('en_CA')
#3 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\LaravelGettextServiceProvider.php(68): Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony->__construct(Object(Xinax\LaravelGettext\Config\Models\Config), Object(Xinax\LaravelGettext\Adapters\LaravelAdapter), Object(Xinax\LaravelGettext\FileSystem), Object(Xinax\LaravelGettext\Storages\SessionStorage))
#4 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(873): Xinax\LaravelGettext\LaravelGettextServiceProvider->Xinax\LaravelGettext{closure}(Object(Illuminate\Foundation\Application), Array)
#5 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(758): Illuminate\Container\Container->build(Object(Closure))
#6 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(851): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('Xinax\LaravelGe...', Array, true)#7 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Container\Container.php(694): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->resolve('Xinax\LaravelGe...', Array)
#8 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Application.php(836): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('Xinax\LaravelGe...', Array)
#9 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php(119): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('Xinax\LaravelGe...', Array)
#10 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\Support\helpers.php(18): app('Xinax\LaravelGe...')
#11 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\app\Exceptions\Handler.php(152): _i('Details')
#12 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(196): App\Exceptions\Handler->render(Object(Illuminate\Http\Request), Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#13 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(173): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->renderHttpResponse(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#14 C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions.php(209): Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleException(Object(Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError))
#15 [internal function]: Illuminate\Foundation\Bootstrap\HandleExceptions->handleShutdown()
#16 {main}
thrown in C:\Users\pragneshc\promis\Promis3.0\promis3.0-laravel\vendor\zerospam\laravel-gettext\src\Xinax\LaravelGettext\Translators\Symfony.php on line 114

and below is the composer.json file

"require": {
"php": "^8.1",
"artisaninweb/laravel-soap": "0.3.0.9",
"barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.8.5",
"fideloper/proxy": "^4.0",
"laravel/framework": "^8.0",
"laravel/homestead": "^13.2",
"laravel/tinker": "^2.0",
"maatwebsite/excel": "^3.1",
"phpoffice/phpspreadsheet": "^1.10",
"zerospam/laravel-gettext": "^8.0"
},
"require-dev": {
"facade/ignition": "^2.3.6",
"fzaninotto/faker": "^1.4",
"mockery/mockery": "^1.0",
"nunomaduro/collision": "^5.1",
"phpunit/phpunit": "^9.0"
},

Answer (score 0):

Laravel 8 is not suitable with php 8.1, so when you run composer, it throw an error because its package is for php 7.3.

Try downgrading your php or update laravel to Laravel 9.